# Active Record "Where" Query Failing to find Record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

So have a token model that has keys which are strings. I am doing a search for a token that exists and when i do a direct comparrison of the string with the record it should find i get an empty active record relation object.

Anyone know what is going on here?  Am i stepping on a models toes by using the Model name 'Token'.  I didn't find anything in the googles about it.

I've stored the key as 'a' below and Token.last.key is the database entry that has the matching key.

```
irb(main):023:0> a
=> "279684d7488254c41bb4039ad0962007"
irb(main):024:0> Token.last.key
  Token Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "tokens".* FROM "tokens"   ORDER BY "tokens"."id" DESC LIMIT 1
=> "279684d7488254c41bb4039ad0962007"
irb(main):025:0> a == Token.last.key 
  Token Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "tokens".* FROM "tokens"   ORDER BY "tokens"."id" DESC LIMIT 1
=> true
irb(main):026:0> Token.where(key: a)
  Token Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "tokens".* FROM "tokens"  WHERE "tokens"."key" = '279684d7488254c41bb4039ad0962007'
=> #<ActiveRecord::Relation []>
irb(main):027:0> Token.where(key: a.to_s)
  Token Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "tokens".* FROM "tokens"  WHERE "tokens"."key" = '279684d7488254c41bb4039ad0962007'
=> #<ActiveRecord::Relation []>
```

Oddly enough, when i do a search through all the records i do return the correct user

```
  #DOES WORK
  def current_user(key)
    Token.all.first {|t| return t.key == key }
  end
```

What i have will work but what i would like it to do this in the database with something like this

```
  #DOES NOT WORK 
  def current_user(key)
    Token.where(key: key).try(:user)
  end
```

Doing search based on suggestion below returning nil for find_by

```
irb(main):004:0> a = Token.last.key
  Token Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "tokens".* FROM "tokens"   ORDER BY "tokens"."id" DESC LIMIT 1
=> "279684d7488254c41bb4039ad0962007"
irb(main):005:0> Token.find_by(key: a)
  Token Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "tokens".* FROM "tokens"  WHERE "tokens"."key" = '279684d7488254c41bb4039ad0962007' LIMIT 1
=> nil
```

Solution was to do this

```
def find_user_by_api(key)
  tokens = Token.arel_table
  Token.where(tokens[:key].matches(key)).try(:first).try(:user)
end
```

Comment: What happens if you try `Token.where(key: Token.last.key)`?

Comment: @fivedigit, i get the same empty active record relation.  It's like it is not able to do the search.  I am going to bet this is going to be due to some reserved words that i'm trampling on with using Token or key.  Searching for user_id (which is another attribute on Token) works correctly.

Comment: @Austio do you use `default_scope` in `Token` model ?

Comment: @itsnikolay No default scope.  Token just belongs_to :user

Answer (score 1):

Wish it helps

```
Token.find_by(key: a)
```

Comment: Thanks but still returns nil, will update question with another observation i just made

Comment: @Austio could you run sql console (`rails db`) and execute `SELECT "tokens".* FROM "tokens"  WHERE "tokens"."key" = '279684d7488254c41bb4039ad0962007'` what's a output ?

Comment: @Austio this is actual answer of your question either you entered a wrong value on `a`

Comment: @Austio but so what's output ? none ?

Comment: @itsnikolay, good idea.  I am getting an empty response running in the db and using SQLite.  Quering for "tokens"."user_id" = 1 does work.  Also tried the '2796...' with double quotes and no quotes with no success.  Cutting this off to SELECT "tokens".* FROM "tokens" displays all the tokens as well.

Comment: @RajarshiDas Added results from rails console to question.

Comment: @Austio could you try execute in db console `SELECT "tokens".* FROM "tokens" WHERE "tokens"."key" LIKE '%279684%'` and then add by one letter `LIKE '%279684d%'` and etc. What's the output?

Comment: what it is return `tokens = Toke.arel_table` `Token.where(tokens[:key].matches("%#{279684}%"))`

Comment: @RajarshiDas sorry i missed the comment.  When i do what you mentioned i get the correct result.  Oddly i started a completely new app and am getting the same problem as above with a renamed tabled (used ApiKey instead of Token).  I'll just use the arel example.